# Функции в качестве параметров

Tags: javascript, функции

Какую функцию выполняет func(), то есть в чем смысл использования этой функции там.

```js
function sum(x, y){
    return x + y;
}
 
function subtract(x, y){
    return x - y;
}
 
function operation(x, y, func){
  
    var result = func(x, y);
    console.log(result);
}
 
console.log("Sum");
operation(10, 6, sum);  // 16
 
console.log("Subtract");
operation(10, 6, subtract); // 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вкратце: *потому что так удобнее*

Давайте разберем общую ситуацию: нужно отсортировать массив. У нас есть функция `sort`, которая принимает массив и сортирует его, а еще нам нужен признак, по которому нужно отсортировать элементы, пусть это будет цена:

```
// Псевдокод
function sort(array) {
  // Реализация какой-то сортировки: быстрая, пузырьковая - неважно
  // Важен вот этот момент:
  if (признак по которому а больше b) {
    // Ставим a первее b
  } else {
    // Наоборот
  }
}
```

И вот у нас есть функция сортировки по цене. Красивая, супербыстрая и эффективная. Только вот вдруг нам понадобилось в другом месте сортировать по дате. Что же делать? Снова писать ту же самую функцию сортировки, только сравнивать даты, а не цену? Если подумать, то различие будет только в одном месте:

```
  if (признак по которому а больше b) {
    // Ставим a первее b
  } else {
    // Наоборот
  }
```

Тут-то нам и помогает вспомогательная функция. Что если вынести этот момент во внешнюю функцию, а остальную сортировку сделать общей? Тогда получится примерно так

```
function sortFn(a, b) {
  if (признак по которому а больше b) {
    // Ставим a первее b
  } else {
    // Наоборот
  }
}

function(array, fn) {
  // Где-то в коде
  sortFn(a, b);
}
```

Теперь у нас есть одна общая функция сортировки, меняется только признаки, по которым мы сортируем, и мы можем описывать их отдельными маленькими функциями, каждый раз не дублируя большую функцию сортировки.

Так же работаю `forEach`, `map`, `filter` - функции, где есть какая-то общая часть, но уникальные условия для каждого конкретного случая.

Что касается вашего случая, он очень простой, чтобы увидеть профит. Но давайте представим, что у нас в функции `operation` происходит еще много чего

```
function operation(x, y, func) {
  // Считаем попугаев, валидируем, взламываем пентагон.
  // много строчек кода...
  // Готово
  var result = func(x, y);
  console.log(result);
}
```

Без третьего параметра, нам бы пришлось делать все доп операции прямо в `sum`, `substract` и вообще в любой операции, что является дублированием кода и плохо масштабируется, а так, вся общая логика в одном месте, меняется лишь главная часть, которая зависит от конкретных желаний.

Как бы было без третьего параметра:

```js
function sumOpeartion(x, y){
    const result =  x + y;
    console.log(result);
}
 
function subtractOperation(x, y){
    const result = x - y;
    console.log(result);
}
 
console.log("Sum");
sumOpeartion(10, 6);  // 16
 
console.log("Subtract");
subtractOperation(10, 6); // 4
```

Comment: Спасибо. Еще понятнее будет если вы напишете это же задание(function sum(x, y){ ..... )  без третьего параметра. Я буду сравнивать их.

Comment: @Afina готово, написал без третьего параметра

Comment: Все понятно. Я с return написала вот так   var m=10;
var n=6;
var result=sumOperation(m,n);
function sumOperation(x,y){
  return x+y;
 
}
console.log("Sum");
console.log(result); Но это думаю не очень-то хороший код. По-другому это можно написать как вы написали но c помощью return?

Comment: ваш код на самом деле нормальный в этом случае, только лучше сначала объявлять функцию, а потом ее использовать)

Comment: Окей, понятно. Спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

func в operation - лишь переменная, в которую вы передаёте другую функцию, когда вызываете operation. Как мы видим - помимо operation есть ещё 2 функции, и когда вы вызываете operation, вы указываете х, у, а так же название функции (sum либо subtract). Внутри operation указанная функция выполняется при обращении к func()

Comment: То есть вот так: var func= sum(x,y)/subtract(x,y) { return x + y/return x-y; } func(10, 7); Правильно поняла?

Comment: omg нет, operation(10, 6, sum) = func(10,6) = sum(10,6) = 10 + 6 = 16 также как operation(10, 6, subtract) = func(10,6) = subtract(10, 6) = 10 - 6 = 4

Comment: вот скриншот, так понятнее мб будет: https://sun9-66.userapi.com/c855632/v855632157/12ad94/OAWGR53KkUY.jpg

Comment: Нет, вы неправильно поняли меня. То есть если без функции operation написать этот код, так же будет(как выше я написала). Там я хотела показать что func эта переменная. Просто в том коде у меня с return внутри фигурных скобок неправильно. Типа вот такого я имела ввиду. var display = function(){ document.write("Hi");} display();